# setValues Exception: Service error: Spreadsheets How to fix range errors?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function chk(){
  //PDD data setting
  var today=new Date();
  var Date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yy-MM-dd");
  
  [{
    sheetName: "Sheet1" ,
    folderID: '(google drive Folder)',
    sheetId: '(sheetId1)',
    tab: ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    conver: Date
  },{
    sheetName: "Sheet2" ,
    folderID: '(google drive Folder)',
    sheetId: '(sheetId1)',
    tab: ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    conver: Date
  }{
    sheetName: "Sheet3" ,
    folderID: '(google drive Folder)',
    sheetId: '(sheetId1)',
    tab: ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    conver: Date
  }].map(obj => cloneValues(obj))
}

  function cloneValues(obj){
  
  let string = obj.conver;
  let A =  obj.sheetName;
  let B = DriveApp.getFolderById(obj.folderID);
  let C = DriveApp.getFileById(obj.sheetId);

  var totalurl =  PastetoDrive.makeCopy('Date '.concat( obj.conver , ' ',obj.sheetName ), dstFolder).getUrl();
  var copy_url = totalurl.split("/");

  let linkSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('(Backup Link sheetId)').getSheetByName('LINK');
  linkSheet.appendRow([ string , A , totalurl ]);

  for(let i = 0; i < obj.tab.length ; i++ ){

    let fromSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(obj.sheetId).getSheetByName(obj.tab[i]);
    let toSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(copy_url[5]).getSheetByName(obj.tab[i]);
    
    setValues(fromSheet,toSheet)
  }
}

    function setValues(fromSheet,toSheet){
        let maxCols = fromSheet.getMaxColumns();
        let maxRows = fromSheet.getMaxRows();
        let frvalues = fromSheet.getRange(1,1,maxRows,maxCols).getValues();
        toSheet.getRange(1,1,maxRows,maxCols).setValues(frvalues);
    }
```

Exception: Service error: Spreadsheets

I am writing and using Google AppScript, a work sheet that performs daily backups.
Exception: Service error: Spreadsheets error started to occur about a month ago in a script that I have been using well.
Looking at the log, there was a problem with setValues.
It seems that the ranges of fromSheet and toSheet don't match.

Daily backups should be stored as values in fromSheet > toSheet .

```
function setValues(fromSheet,toSheet){
  const range = fromSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  return toSheet.range;
}
```

Once I changed the function setValues syntax and used it, I tried using setValues(range) to save it as a value, but it was not enough.

I'm a script beginner. I am testing and using various articles I need on stackoverflow and GitHub by combining and changing them.
Can anyone help me again this time?

Comment: What range errors? Why are you using maxRows and maxColumns in your setValues() function?

Comment: @cooper This is because you want to back up the original sheet as it is :)
There are a total of 3 backup sheets.
These sheets have different Col and Row.
I tried using getLastRow & Col , but it repeats the same error.
Exception: Service error: Spreadsheets

Comment: Hi, this is not reproducible on my side. If I execute `chd` (and change all the placeholders accordingly) I can successfully set the values from `fromSheet` to `toSheet`. (1) What line exactly are you getting this error?, (2) Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including, if necessary, copies of the spreadsheets you are working on?, (3) What's the code related to `PastetoDrive`?, (4) What's the relation between `chkrowcol` and the rest of your code?

Comment: (1) >
A: line 202
B: line 223
C: complete

total Row 250 | Col 170

(2) >
It is a pity that we cannot share an example sheet due to the company's security policy. (No access through G-suit)

(3)>
The backed up files are stored in Google Drive,
Write the backup file access link in the LINK tab of the Backup Link sheet

(4) >
The chkrowcol code is Row | Col This is the 'original' of the code that I tried to check because an error occurred. It has nothing to do with the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: (1) I meant which line in your code. Also I don't understand that you are getting an error on row 202 of column A, 223 of column B?. (2) Even if you cannot share the spreadsheet, can you at least provide a screenshot to understand the data structure?, (3) I don't understand this explanation, can you provide the code in which `PastetoDrive` is defined?

Comment: Thank you for your interest.
1) A sheet: 202 rows B sheet: 223 rows C sheet: all rows 250 rows
2) .
3) According to the company's internal regulations, the entire script or sheet cannot be shared, so it seems that the script I wrote as an example caused a misunderstanding...
sorry.
```let PastetoDrive = DriveApp.getFileById(obj.sheetId);

  var totalurl =  PastetoDrive.makeCopy('DATE '.concat( obj.conver, ' ',obj.sheetName ),```
Apologies for the syntax on the original sheet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function setValues(fromSheet,tosheet){

  try {
    const range = fromSheet.getRange(1, 1, tosheet.getMaxRows(), tosheet.getMaxColumns());
    const values = range.getValues();
    const toRange = tosheet.getRange(1, 1, tosheet.getMaxRows(), tosheet.getMaxColumns()).getA1Notation();
    return tosheet.getRange(toRange).setValues(values);

  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e);
  }

}
```

[image]
to-be

[image]
as-is

As a result, it was successful.
Posting a question and waiting for help from many people, I tried various methods, but nothing improved and I kept getting **Service Error: Spreadsheet** text.

In the end, I changed some of the `setValues` syntax and
I tried setting the range again, but the same error occurred.
After confirming that the result of the clone sheet is the result I want,
Decided to avoid this issue.
`catch(e)`

Thank you for your interest.